# Wipe AppData/Roaming after ClickOnce application uninstalled

Tags: clickonce, uninstallation, sensitive-data

I have a .NET application that operates with sensitive content. So after it is uninstalled I want to be certain all its data has been completely removed from device' storage. All the data the app stores is placed to c:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming[Application] and persists after the application is uninstalled but it shall not.

My application is distributed within a ClickOnce installer.

How do I make it wipe all the data when a user uninstall is via Control Panel?

I found few words on how to clear application cache stored in c:\Users[username]\AppData\Local, but it isn't what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

see this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/506162/ClickOnce-application-autostart-and-clean-uninstal - i do use it, and it's quite helpful. Using code from the article, you can write your own "uninstall" procedure and remove whatever data you want.